# xcode "Developer" folder

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4, xcode4.5

I've been working on an Ipad app for awhile now and to make the development a little faster I've been using some controls I found on the interwebz. Namely FSVerticalTabBar , AES Encryption.

It's just now that I noticed 2 folders inside every folder on my project which I didn't noticed before. the thing with these folders I can't select them with a mouse, I have to highlight it with the cursor, So I couldn't delete them. Was wondering if it's something I should be worried about or is it really include in xcode that I just never noticed before?

The folders are :

Folder and Developer
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're seeing a bug in Finder. I've seen the same thing on occasion. If you restart your computer, it should go away.

Answer (score 0):

They may be a problem. From your extended explanation of the problem it sounds like something is wrong with finder. This could be a wacky extension or something more serious. Its really hard to say given the extent of your issue.

Comment: do you have any idea on how that got there? also, I'm very new with mac os, so not really sure how to go about unlinking.

Comment: i have no idea, it happened in one of my projects before, i dont know why, something to do with the way i added a folder to xcode that was already inside itself or something i think.

Comment: ok so I tried unlinking them. I navigated to the project folder and did "ls" , and the Folders doesn't show up. did "cd" and it would say "No such file or directory". This is weird.

Comment: nope. still nothing. Also, I just checked, these folders are all over the HD. Every folder in my HD basically has either "Folders" or "Folders and Developer"

Comment: hmm sounds like a bigger issue gdubs. maybe some kind of wierd finder extension gone crazy sounds like they are ghost files/folders i didnt really understand the extent of your issue.